# Safe way to remove a symbolic link to an non-existing directory (for the python binary)

Tags: bash, directory, symlink

I accidentally typed:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.5/ /usr/bin/python
```

instead of:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.5 /usr/bin/python
```

Now bash tells me that /usr/bin/python is not a directory whenever I run python.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python gives me expectedly /usr/bin/python --> /usr/local/bin/python2.5/
```

Is there any safe way to remove that symbolic link to a directory (that does not exist) and replace it with a link to the intended file?

Arigato in advance if you have any ideas.

I am stuck....

Answer (score 7):

you can simply remove the link with rm :

```
rm /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: won't that remove the whole binary file?

Comment: @uploada: No, `rm` on a symlink just removes the symlink, not what it points to.

Answer (score 1):

You remove a symlink the same way you remove a regular file, even if it's a symlink to a directory. (If the target doesn't exist, it's a moot point whether it was intended to be a directory or a file.)

Comment: awesome it works. just was too scared about the action. realized that it was just a link.Tks

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me. Although I originally created the symlink following a blender tutorial
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Troubleshooting#Setting_Python_Path_in_SCons

using this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /your/path/to/python3.2 1
```

(see man page for update-alternatives for info.  Terminal>man update-alternatives)

I'm curious to know how badly I've messed things up for the update-alternatives system of managing different versions of same-named software.  For instance, i think scons runs on python2.7 while blender builds internally with python3.2.  Will things resolve correctly still?  We shall see...