# Refercing Python 3.7.3 in subshell during cron job

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, cron

I'm using Amazon Linux with Python 2.7.16 preinstalled. Currently, I'm doing a cron job, trying to run python in a shell script using Python 3.7.3. I have it available at `/usr/local/bin/python3.7` and `alias python=python3.7` in `~/.bashrc`.

However, when I call `which python` in the shell script. I'm getting `/usr/bin/python` instead. I have tried `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` but failed because is searching for `python` instead of `python3.7`.

Ultimately, when I run any `python` command in the shell script, I would like to reference `/usr/local/bin/python3.7` without explicitly refering to it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheduling a python 3.6 script in using crontab/cron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45740940/608639), [How do I setup a cron to run specifically with python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57894681/608639), [Crontab not running my python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135), etc. Also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639), [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create symbolic link to the binary

```sh
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python
```

if the file under `/usr/bin/python` already exists (it probably does), then rename it or backup it in other way.

([Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133025/safe-way-to-remove-a-symbolic-link-to-an-non-existing-directory-for-the-python))

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbolic link to solve this :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
unlink /usr/local/bin/python
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```